# How can we save multiple query results when only one appears?

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to calculate the average and maximum speed of 20 fruit flies. I have a database named `CSV_DAM_ACTIVITY` in which there is 20 columns one for each fly. Each line represent the movement made during a minute by fly X. Once I open the database in DB Browser for SQLite I enter the window "running SQL". I have no difficulty to obtain the maximum and average speed for 1 fly by entering: `select max(ROI_1), avg(ROI_1) as moyenne from CSV_DAM_ACTIVITY;` But when I try to obtain the results for all the flies I only see the last result: maximum and average speed for fly 20.

I first tried to save the data into a table:

```
    create table z (a int not null,b int not null);
    insert into t values ( max(ROI_1)from CSV_DAM_ACTIVITY , avg(ROI_1) ) from  CSV_DAM_ACTIVITY);
    select * from t ;
```

But I got the Following error:

```
   Result: near "from": syntax error
   At line 1:
   insert into t values( max(ROI_1)from
```

I also tried :

```
   create table droso ( maxi1 int not null , moyenne1 int not null ,   maxi2 int not null ,   moyenne2 int not null ,   maxi3 int not null ,   moyenne3 int not null ,    maxi4 int not null ,   moyenne4 int not null , maxi5 int not null ,   moyenne5 int not null ,  maxi6 int not null ,   moyenne6 int not null ,  maxi7 int not null ,   moyenne7 int not null ,   maxi8 int not null ,   moyenne8 int not null , maxi9 int not null ,   moyenne9 int not null ,  maxi10 int not null ,   moyenne10 int not null , maxi11 int not null ,   moyenne11 int not null ,   maxi12 int not null ,   moyenne12 int not null ,   maxi13 int not null ,   moyenne13 int not null ,  maxi14 int not null ,   moyenne14 int not null , maxi15 int not null ,   moyenne15 int not null ,  maxi16 int not null ,   moyenne16 int not null ,  maxi17 int not null ,   moyenne17 int not null ,  maxi18 int not null ,   moyenne18 int not null ,  maxi19 int not null ,   moyenne19 int not null ,  maxi20 int not null ,   moyenne20 int not null) ;
   insert into droso select max(ROI_1),avg(ROI_1),  max(ROI_2),  avg(ROI_2),  max(ROI_3),  avg(ROI_3),   max(ROI_4),  avg(ROI_4),max(ROI_5),  avg(ROI_5) , max(ROI_6),  avg(ROI_6) , max(ROI_7),  avg(ROI_7),  max(ROI_8),  avg(ROI_8) ,max(ROI_9),  avg(ROI_9), max(ROI_10),  avg(ROI_10) ,max(ROI_11),  avg(ROI_11),  max(ROI_12),  avg(ROI_12),  max(ROI_13),  avg(ROI_13), max(ROI_14),  avg(ROI_14),max(ROI_15),  avg(ROI_15), max(ROI_16),  avg(ROI_16), max(ROI_17),  avg(ROI_17), max(ROI_18),  avg(ROI_18), max(ROI_19),  avg(ROI_19), max(ROI_20),  avg(ROI_20),from CSV_DAM_ACTIVITY ;
   select * from droso ;
```

But got the same error

Then I tried to have all the results displayed directly by taping:

```
 select max(ROI_1), avg(ROI_1) as moyenne from CSV_DAM_ACTIVITY; 
   select max(ROI_2), avg(ROI_2) as moyenne from CSV_DAM_ACTIVITY;
   select max(ROI_3), avg(ROI_3) as moyenne from CSV_DAM_ACTIVITY;
   select max(ROI_4), avg(ROI_4) as moyenne from CSV_DAM_ACTIVITY;
   select max(ROI_5),  avg(ROI_5) as moyenne from CSV_DAM_ACTIVITY;
   select max(ROI_6), avg(ROI_6) as moyenne from CSV_DAM_ACTIVITY;
   select max(ROI_7), avg(ROI_7) as moyenne from CSV_DAM_ACTIVITY;
   select max(ROI_8), avg(ROI_8) as moyenne from CSV_DAM_ACTIVITY;
   select max(ROI_9), avg(ROI_9) as moyenne from CSV_DAM_ACTIVITY;
   select max(ROI_10), avg(ROI_10) as moyenne from CSV_DAM_ACTIVITY;
   select max(ROI_11), avg(ROI_11) as moyenne from CSV_DAM_ACTIVITY; 
   select max(ROI_12), avg(ROI_12) as moyenne from CSV_DAM_ACTIVITY;
   select max(ROI_13), avg(ROI_13) as moyenne from CSV_DAM_ACTIVITY;
   select max(ROI_14), avg(ROI_14) as moyenne from CSV_DAM_ACTIVITY;
   select max(ROI_15), avg(ROI_15) as moyenne from CSV_DAM_ACTIVITY;
   select max(ROI_16), avg(ROI_16) as moyenne from CSV_DAM_ACTIVITY;
   select max(ROI_17), avg(ROI_17) as moyenne from CSV_DAM_ACTIVITY;
   select max(ROI_18), avg(ROI_18) as moyenne from CSV_DAM_ACTIVITY;
   select max(ROI_19), avg(ROI_19) as moyenne from CSV_DAM_ACTIVITY;
   select max(ROI_20), avg(ROI_20) as moyenne from CSV_DAM_ACTIVITY;`
```

It only showed the results of fly 20

I tried to put it all in one instruction:

```
   select max(ROI_1),avg(ROI_1),  max(ROI_2),  avg(ROI_2),  max(ROI_3),  avg (ROI_3),   max(ROI_4),  avg(ROI_4),max(ROI_5),  avg(ROI_5) , max(ROI_6),  avg(ROI_6) , max(ROI_7),  avg(ROI_7),  max(ROI_8),  avg(ROI_8) ,max(ROI_9),  avg(ROI_9), max(ROI_10),  avg(ROI_10) ,max(ROI_11),  avg(ROI_11),  max(ROI_12),  avg(ROI_12),  max(ROI_13),  avg(ROI_13), max(ROI_14),  avg(ROI_14),max(ROI_15),  avg(ROI_15), max(ROI_16),  avg(ROI_16), max(ROI_17),  avg(ROI_17), max(ROI_18),  avg(ROI_18), max(ROI_19),  avg(ROI_19), max(ROI_20),  avg(ROI_20),  from CSV_DAM_ACTIVITY ;
```

It showed the following error: `result: near "from":syntax error`

Comment: Dangling comma: Replace `avg(ROI_20),` with `avg(ROI_20)` ... but not sure if there might be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The errors you get are syntax errors.
The 1st statement:

```
create table z (a int not null,b int not null);
insert into t values ( max(ROI_1)from CSV_DAM_ACTIVITY , avg(ROI_1) ) from  CSV_DAM_ACTIVITY);
select * from t ;
```

should be written:

```
create table z (a int not null,b int not null);
insert into z(a, b) 
select max(ROI_1), avg(ROI_1) from CSV_DAM_ACTIVITY;
```

You can find more here: [SQLite Insert](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-insert/)
This will insert into the new table `z` 1 row with values `max(ROI_1)` and `avg(ROI_1)`.
In the 2nd and the last statement remove the last comma before `from`.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a table that looks something like:

```
CREATE TABLE CSV_DAM_ACTIVITY(ROI_1, ROI_2, ..., ROI_20);
```

A better table design would hold each fly's speed at a given timestamp in a single row:

```
CREATE TABLE fly_data(fly_id INTEGER, minute INTEGER, speed NUMERIC,
                      PRIMARY KEY(fly_id, minute)) WITHOUT ROWID;
```

Then you can get a list of each fly's maximum and average speeds with:

```
SELECT fly_id, max(speed), avg(speed) FROM fly_data GROUP BY fly_id ORDER BY fly_id;
```

The easiest way to transform your CSV data into this structure is probably a quick [ETL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) perl (Or python or whatever scripting language you like) script that turns 1 row of the CSV file into 20 inserts.

```
INSERT INTO fly_data(fly_id, minute, speed) VALUES(1, 1, $row_1_col_1_value);
INSERT INTO fly_data(fly_id, minute, speed) VALUES(2, 1, $row_1_col_2_value);
...
INSERT INTO fly_data(fly_id, minute, speed) VALUES(1, 20, $row_20_col_1_value);
-- etc.
```

or maybe directly in sqlite with a bunch of inserts like

```
INSERT INTO fly_data(fly_id, minute, speed)
  SELECT 1, rowid, roi_1 FROM CSV_DAM_ACTIVITY;
INSERT INTO fly_data(fly_id, minute, speed)
  SELECT 2, rowid, roi_2 FROM CSV_DAM_ACTIVITY;
-- and so on
```

as long as the fairly safe assumption that `CSV_DAM_ACTIVITY`'s [rowid](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid) values represent the insertion order of the rows (And thus timestamps) from the CSV file is true.

([WITHOUT ROWID](https://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html) description)